# How to turn the coordinate found from distance matrix to be positive?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

t = np.random.randint(0, 50, (10, 10)) 
X = tpca = PCA(n_components=2) 
X3d = pca.fit_transform(X) 
X3d= np.round(X3d, 2) 
print (X3d)
```

How to turn the coordinate found from distance matrix to be positive?

Comment: There is only code in your question, what is actual problem? Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve? Adding current and expected output could be also helpful, better check how to correctly ask a question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to solve. The is current output: [[ -7.55  26.71]
 [ 54.18  -9.22]
 [  4.51  28.92]
 [ -5.93 -23.76]
 [ 13.94 -20.91]
 [-34.   -13.51]
 [  7.13  30.95]
 [-24.24  11.91]
 [ 13.18  -9.58]
 [-21.21 -21.5 ]]

Comment: and I try to turn all of these sign to be positive for my mapping. And I found that svd_flip() can effectively solve this and in figuring to define it under which category as the onine resource is less. If u can help, then will much more appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute, import math library and use `abs()`.
example:

```
import math

distance = -40
print(abs(distance))
```

Output:

```
40
```

Comment: [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) on its own is a built-in. The `math` package has [`math.fabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fabs).